# Hi I am wring activex control in VB. In this I have EXIT button. If EXIT is clicked application should get closed. How to do this?

Tags: vb.net, com

Hi I am writing activex control in VB. In this I have EXIT button. If EXIT is clicked application should get closed. How to do this??

Comment: It is not the job of a control to terminate a program.  Raise an event with the Click event handler.  The client app that uses your control can subscribe it and act accordingly.  Pretty unlikely it will, you cannot enforce these things, so don't bother.

Answer (score 2):

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Form1.close()
End Sub
```

EDIT:
on VB.net, Form1 is recognized as the main window, when its closed, all the forms exits.

Comment: You are right but the thing is I am writing button1 in user control library and I will add this new control to my windows form. If I click button1 the whole application should get closed.
so how can I perform Close() on windows form through windows forms control library

Comment: you are absolutely write. The button1 control has been defined in user control library and through this I want to close the form where I used that user defined control.

Comment: This is the correct answer. As an aside, make sure that in your "My Project" you have set "Shutdown Mode" properly based on how you want your program to close (either when startup form closes, or last form closes)

Comment: I don't really get you now. Maybe you are writing this code on a wrong button event. don't you think @Malky.Kid?

Comment: See, I'm creating an UserControl to which is having only a Button(say Close) (purpose of this button is to close form only). Now once I build this I will get the .dll file of this control. Now I will create an windows form . In this I will add .dll (which is created by user as I said earlier) in toolbox so that this control will also work like other controls available in .NET framework. Now I will drag and drop this userControl to the form(say Form1). Now If I build this application and click on Button( ie Close which is defined in userControl), the form, Form1, should get closed.how to do ths